# Summing up all elements in a list of 2D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list `QS` of n 2d arrays. Now I want to sum up all the arrays in the list, so that I end up with another 2d array. So far, I did this manually, since my number of list elements was small, e.g.:

```
n=6    
QM=QS[0]+QS[1]+QS[2]+QS[3]+QS[4]+QS[5]
```

But now I need to consider more elements of the list and I'm looking for a more pythonic way to do that. I've tried the following:

```
QQ=map(sum, zip(QS))
```

But it gives me a list of the sums of the elements of the arrays in the original list, not the sum of the arrays themselves. 
There must be a simple way to do this, I just haven't figured it out yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide some sample input/output data, it's not clear what exactly are you looking for.

Comment: will doing a sum of the result of map give you the result you want? Not totally sure what you're asking of though.

Comment: maybe it gets clear if we regard the shapes: QS is a list containing 6 arrays of shape 64x16: `np.shape(QS)=>(6,64,16)`
What I want is the sum of the 6 arrays in QS: `np.shape(QQ)=>(64,16)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `np.sum`, IIUC:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> QS = [np.random.randint(0, 10, (3,3)) for i in range(6)]
>>> QM = QS[0]+QS[1]+QS[2]+QS[3]+QS[4]+QS[5]
>>> QM
array([[36, 32, 32],
       [34, 28, 30],
       [28, 28, 32]])
>>> QM2 = np.sum(QS,axis=0)
>>> QM2
array([[36, 32, 32],
       [34, 28, 30],
       [28, 28, 32]])
>>> np.allclose(QM, QM2)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the equivalent of putting the lists with `+` between them:

```
QM = []
map(lambda l: QM.extend(l), QS)
```

without map:

```
for l in QS:
    QM.extend(l)
```

or simply:

```
for l in QS:
    QM += l
```

Comment: Don't use `map` or list comprehension for side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

Without your array, it's hard to see what exactly will work. But try something like this to sum an array of arrays (list of lists):

```
sum([sum(i) for i in zip(*QS)])
```

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13783363/2327328)

Answer (score 0):

If you whant to convert 2D list into 1D, try this:

```
>>> a = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
>>> sum(a, [])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>>
```

Comment: Even [Python's doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) don't recommend this.