# Summing a 2d array in Python 3.x

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, sum

new to programming and Python, using Python 3.x, I have to create a function that adds all the elements in a 2D array, the
function should return the addition of all the elements of an array.
I have to use 2 for loops to traverse the array and add up all the
elements and I can't use any summing functions.

This is what I have so far but it is not functional

```
def add2D(array):
    for row in array:
        for entry in row:
            print(entry, end='  ')
        print()

    sum = 0
    for row in array (len(input)):
        for col in array(len(input[0])-1):
            sum = sum + input[row][col]
return sum
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What's `input` supposed to be?

Comment: oops forgot to change that, input is the array i.e. array = [ [1,6,3], [2,10,7], [3,4,100] ]

Comment: A big part of learning Python is learning to understand error messages. Did you receive one when you ran this code?

Comment: add2D(array)
 1 6 3
 2 10 7
 3 4 100
Total of the array is: 136

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783315/sum-of-list-of-lists-returns-sum-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it. Here's a working version

```
def add2D(array):
    for row in array:
        for entry in row:
            print(entry, end='  ')
        print()

    sum = 0
    for row in array:
        for col in row:
            sum = sum + col
    return sum
```

Comment: ah, leave it to me to overthink it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using range where possible. Below one should work. First iterate over every innerList and then traverse every element of the innerList and add them with your `sum` variable.

```
def add2D(array):
    sum=0
    for row in array:
        for num in row:
            sum+=num
     return sum
```