# Python sum first element of a list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there any way to plus the first element of a list easily
Wat I need to do is something like this:

```
Lista1 = [[5,7,6,4,3], [8,7,6,14,5],[5,7,8,6,9]]
```

Result

```
18  21  20  24  17
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Kasramvd not really a dupe of that one, but don't reopen, there are already good answers anyway (and it's probably a dupe of some other Q&A)

Comment: Here is an exact dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783315/sum-of-list-of-lists-returns-sum-list

Comment: @Kasramvd: found a better one. _everything is a duplicate_ ....

Comment: @Kasramvd removed your first dupe link, added your new one (and linked the 2 q&a together). Talk about doing work for free here :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks ;)

Answer (score 12):

Of course there is a way:

```
map(sum, zip(*Lista1))
```

Here, `zip(*Lista1)` transposes `Lista1`, `map(sum, ...)` applies the `sum` function to each list of the transposed list.

Comment: Perhaps it'd be a better idea to wait and let the OP show what they've tried? Nice answer though.

Comment: @ChristianDean, right, but I doubt they actually tried anything. I think it'd be good to show them the power of Python so that they'd be eager to study it more thoroughly.

Comment: ... and stop playing with that vote button :)

Comment: it's probably a duplicate, but not easy to find. I'll try.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, who, me? I'm not upvoting or downvoting anyone right now.

Comment: @ForceBru I was joking about the fact that your answer votes was 1, 2, 1, 2..

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, yeah, I noticed this too. Someone was reeeeally unsure whether to upvote or not:D

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Hey! I only toggled my vote _once_ ;-)

Comment: @ChristianDean I'm a nervous guy :)

Answer (score 3):

One liner using `list comprehension` :

```
>>> [ sum(row[i] for row in l) for i in range(len(l[0])) ]
```

#driver values :

```
IN : l = [[5,7,6,4,3], [8,7,6,14,5],[5,7,8,6,9]]
OUT : [18, 21, 20, 24, 17]
```

**NOTE :** I would suggest going with the answers done using `zip`. More *pythonic* and *better run time*.

Answer (score 3):

[NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) is a good method for achieving this. You can use `np.sum` and specify which axis you want to sum over. For example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[5,7,6,4,3],[8,7,6,14,5],[5,7,8,6,9]], dtype=int)
np.sum(a, axis=0)
array([18, 21, 20, 24, 17])
```

Comment: This is definitely overkill. I think you could do the same with a neural network with TensorFlow.

Comment: Yes, perhaps, but for large multidimensional arrays using the numpy method, this will provide a much-needed speed improvement due to the element-wise operations that numpy provides.